# Assigning a viewbag to a variable in a JQuery function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I'm using MVC and am trying to check if the item has enough stock in inventory. I do this in my controller by

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Audit]
        public void AddUnits(int so_id, int site_id, int[] addItem_id, int[] addItem_qty)
        {
            // Loop however many times is necessary to iterate through the largest array
            for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(Math.Max(addItem_id.Length, addComp_id.Length), addPart_id.Length); i++)
            {
                foreach (SODetails sod in db.SalesOrders.Find(so_id).SalesDetails)
                {
                    if (i < addItem_id.Length && addItem_qty[i] != 0 && sod.ItemID == addItem_id[i] && addItem_id[i] != 365 && addItem_id[i] != 410) 
                    {

                        sod.item_qty += addItem_qty[i];
                        sod.item_discount = addItem_disc[i];
                        addItem_id[i] = 0;
                        addItem_qty[i] = 0;
                        addItem_disc[i] = 0;
                    }

                }
                db.SaveChanges();

                if(i < addItem_qty.Length && addItem_qty[i] != 0)
                {
                    SODetails sODetails = new SODetails
                    {
                        SalesOrderID = so_id,
                        SiteID = site_id
                    };

                    // Only add a unit to the SODetails object if it's not null and has an id and quanitity specified
                    if(i < addItem_id.Length && addItem_id[i] != 0 && addItem_qty[i] != 0)
                    {
                        sODetails.ItemID = addItem_id[i];
                        sODetails.item_qty = addItem_qty[i];
                        sODetails.item_discount = addItem_disc[i];
                    }


                    SalesOrder SO = db.SalesOrders.Find(sODetails.SalesOrderID);
                    SODetails salesOrderDetails = db.SODetails.Add(sODetails);
                    salesOrderDetails.SalesOrder = SO;

                    Item SO_Item = db.Items.Find(sODetails.ItemID);

                    if (SO_Item != null)
                    {
                        ViewBag.itemOnHand = SO_Item.On_Hand;

                        sODetails.item_qty = sODetails.item_qty == null ? 0 : sODetails.item_qty;
                        int qtyOrdered = sODetails.item_qty == null ? 0 : (int)sODetails.item_qty;
                        salesOrderDetails.dynamicItem_qty = qtyOrdered;

                        if (SO_Item.SalesOrderMessage != null)
                            TempData["SalesOrderMessage"] = SO_Item.SalesOrderMessage;
                    }

                    }
                }
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Currently I'm trying to pass the inventory count of that item into the viewbag by doing 
`ViewBag.itemOnHand = SO_Item.On_Hand;`

Then my view Jquery function looks like this

```
 // Get all item ids and quantities and store them in arrays
        var itemssel = document.getElementsByClassName("Item-select");
        var itemsqtysel = document.getElementsByClassName("Item-qty");
        var itemsdiscsel = document.getElementsByClassName("Item-disc");
        var itemOnHand = @ViewBag.itemOnHand;
        for (i = 0; i < itemssel.length; i++) {
            items[i] = itemssel[i].options[itemssel[i].selectedIndex].value;
            itemsqty[i] = itemsqtysel[i].value;
            itemsdisc[i] = itemsdiscsel[i].value;
            if (itemsqty[i] < 0) {
                alert("Quantities can't be negative!");
                return;
            }      
            if (itemsqty[i] < itemOnHand) {
                alert("Not enough inventory in site!");
                return;
            }

// The add units method is then called here

 // Send all the values to the AJAX function and respond with success or error 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@IGT.baseUrl/SODetailsAjax/AddUnits",
            traditional: true,
            data: {
                __RequestVerificationToken: token, 
                so_id: @Int32.Parse(Request["orderId"]),
                site_id: site,
                addItem_id: items,
                addItem_qty: itemsqty,
                addItem_disc: itemsdisc,
                addComp_id: comps,
                addComp_qty: compsqty,
                addComp_disc: compsdisc,
                addPart_id: parts,
                addPart_qty: partsqty,
                addPart_disc: partsdisc
            },
            success: function () {
                location.href = "../SalesOrders/Details?id=@so.ID";
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                alert("Error: " + error);
            }
        });
```

But it doesn't work correctly as it is right now. Why is this?

As requested, here is my GET method for the page before it posts

```
        // GET: SODetails/Create
        [RestrictAccess(restriction = AccessRestrictions.ModifySalesOrder)]
        public ActionResult Create(int orderId)
        {
            var SOID = (from i in db.SalesOrders.Where(x => x.ID == orderId).Where(x => x.deleted == false)
                        select new
                        {
                            SO_id = i.ID,
                            status = i.ID + " (Status: " + i.SalesOrderStatus +")",
                        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.SO_id).ToList();

            var item = (from i in db.Items.Where(x => x.deleted == false)
                        select new
                        {
                            itemID = i.ID,
                            itemName = i.Product_Number + " : " + i.ItemID + " : " + i.Name
                        }).OrderBy(x => x.itemName).ToList();

            var component = (from c in db.Components.Where(x => x.deleted == false)

                             select new
                             {
                                 compID = c.ID,
                                 compName = c.Product_Number + " : " + c.ComponentID + " : " + c.Name
                             }).OrderBy(x => x.compName).ToList();

            var part = (from c in db.Parts.Where(x => x.deleted == false)

                        select new
                        {
                            partID = c.ID,
                            partName = c.Product_Number + " : " + c.PartID + " : " + c.Name
                        }).OrderBy(x => x.partName).ToList();
            var sites = (from s in db.Sites
                         select new
                         {
                             siteID = s.ID,
                             siteName = s.Name
                         }).OrderBy(x => x.siteName).ToList();

            sites.Insert(0, new { siteID = 0, siteName = "Main Inventory" });

            var masters = db.Items.Where(x => x.Product_Number.Contains("106101") || x.ItemID.Contains("106101"));
            List<int> ids = new List<int>();
            foreach(Item i in masters.Where(x => x.Product_Number.Contains("BMU") || x.Product_Number.Contains("BMDU") || x.Product_Number.Contains("BMS")))
            {
                ids.Add(i.ID);
            }
            ViewBag.BMUMasters = ids.ToArray();
            ids = new List<int>();
            foreach (Item i in masters.Where(x => x.Product_Number.Contains("GMU")))
            {
                ids.Add(i.ID);
            }
            ViewBag.GMUMasters = ids.ToArray();
            ViewBag.ItemID = new SelectList(item, "itemID", "itemName");
            ViewBag.ComponentID = new SelectList(component, "compID", "compName");
            ViewBag.PartID = new SelectList(part, "partID", "partName");
            ViewBag.SalesOrderID = new SelectList(SOID, "SO_id", "status");
            ViewBag.SiteID = new SelectList(sites, "siteID", "siteName");
            ViewBag.invSiteID = new SelectList(sites, "siteID", "siteName");
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add null coalescing, this will return 0 if the `ViewBag.itemOnHand` is empty;

```
var itemOnHand = @(ViewBag.itemOnHand ?? 0);
```

Then if you're going to use it for some number operations try to force it to become an integer;

```
var itemOnHand = Number(@(ViewBag.itemOnHand ?? 0));
```

Since you already have an if statement or null checks prior to ViewBag assignment, you could simply return the view and add a `ViewBag.Error`;

```
if (SO_Item != null)
{
   // .. if not null
}else{
   // if null return view
   ViewBag.Error = "your error here";
   return View();
}
```

Then somewhere in your view add this;

```
@if(ViewBag.Error != null){
   <div class="row error">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         Error occured: <strong>@ViewBag.Error</strong>
      </div>
   </div>
}
```

Comment: After more testing I found out that it returns 0 everytime. Which it shouldn't

Comment: Just noticed it never gets to  where the viewbag is populated before it performs the check so that is my issue. I'm not sure how I can make it do the check after the method is called however

Comment: this might be empty everytime then `Item SO_Item = db.Items.Find(sODetails.ItemID);` will you add a breakpoint and see if there it's empty?

Comment: Yeah the problem is that it is doing the check before it goes to the method, not after it.

Comment: Not sure what my best solution here is. Maybe I have to get the method to throw the error message from the 'AddUnits' Method? I'm just not sure how to throw a peaceful error message to the user from a void method

Comment: @chris will you include AddUnits non-POST controller action? Or the controller action that precedes your Http Post.

Comment: Okay I added it in and also added how addunits is being called

Comment: But the problem in the method just continues on anyways. The viewbag gets filled but the database changes occur when they shouldn't and the page directs to the next page. It doesn't return to the same page